# Can't solve this seemingly simple equation for x

Tags: functions

I have the following implicit function:

$b x^\frac{2}{a}+(xz+t)^\frac{2}{a} = 1$

which I'm trying to solve for $x$. I've been trying for a while now and I'm unable to simplify anything. This task would be easy if it wasn't for the $t$.

I'm probably missing some trick in my arsenal that makes this possible.

Any help that leads to the correct solution would be greatly appreciated!

To give some context:

I want to calculate the intersection between a superellipsoid/convex superquadric in 3 dimensions and a line $(0, 0, t)^\top + \beta(x, y, z)^\top$. The implicit function of a superellipsoid can be written as $F(x, y, z) = (x^{\frac{2}{e_2}} + y^{\frac{2}{e_2}})^{\frac{e_2}{e_1}} 
+ z^{\frac{2}{e_1}} = 1$ with $0 \leq e_1, e_2, \leq 2$. To calculate the intersection we can solve $F(\beta x, \beta y, \beta z + t) = 1$ for $\beta$. I substituted $(x^{\frac{2}{e_2}} + y^{\frac{2}{e_2}})^{\frac{e_2}{e_1}}$ with $b$
and that is how I got the equation above (although $x$ should probably be called $\beta$ again).

Comment: What makes you th8n' there'd be a closed form for $x?$

Comment: The first thing I'd do )s replace $2/a$ by a single variable. But I doubt there is a closed form.

Comment: In general, this can be written as $b_1x^c+b_2(x+\alpha)^c=1.$ But I doubt there is an easy closed formula even when $c$ is an integer.

Comment: Can you provide some context for why you want to consider this implicit function? Is it part of a larger problem, or did you just make this one up specifically (which I doubt)?

Comment: For $a=2/5$ you'll get a quintic equation, and probably  Abel-Ruffini theorem can be used to prove that the equation won't have a solution (by radicals).

Comment: You can get a [series expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim%5Bsum%5B1%2Fn%21+D%5B%28%281%2F30-%28-1.5%29%2F30+%28x%2B0.3%29%5E5.3%29%5E%281%2F5.3%29%29%5En%2C%7Bx%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C10%7D%5D%2Cx-%3E0.0%5D) for a [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281%2F30-%28-1.5%29%2F30+%28x%2B0.3%29%5E5.3%29%5E%281%2F5.3%29%3Dx), use the complex root for complex solutions, and maybe use binomial series to evaluate the derivatives. This could give a double series solution.